# Text and Checkmarks Extraction from an Image

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, image-recognition

I am working on a project where in I have a filled form which is a safety inspection checklist and I am processing it through AWS Textract.

I am able to fetch text, layout, tables, signatures but Textract is not fetching any checkmarks

Here are two examples:

[image: Snapshot of checkmarks not recognized - Image1]

[image: Snapshot of checkmarks recognized - Image2]

I am looking for guidance into which ML/DL Algo would help me to be able to identify these checkmarks from Image1. Do I need to train a custom solution or is there a pre-trained python library I can use to tune the parameters and identify the checks.